# Extract element from a shuffled list (based off of user's input)

Tags: python, random

I have something like this:

```
s=[7777,5454,75000,4545,787,16000,1000,9888,7854,12223]
random.shuffle(s)
ans=input('Press a number from 0 to 9')
```

I want to associate the input number ans with the s[ans] element. I can do it with 10 if loops, is this the only chance? //SOLVED this

Done that, I want to repeat the random extraction until user digits something like "stop" (here I am) and then sum all the value extracted until "stop" string. How can I do this last point?

Thanks all!

Comment: Have you tried s[ans] yet? that's precisely how you select an item from a list!

Comment: Thank you, first problem solved, that was so easy, I spent too many times in front of my code (it's a long one)

Comment: I don't understand. Are you looking to remove these items from the list or get them from the list or both?

Comment: No I don't want to remove anything from the list. I want to repeat the loop and sum all the extracted element of s (until user answers "no" or "stop" at an hyphotetical question 'do you want to continue')

Comment: First of all, an `if` conditional is most certainly NOT a loop.

Answer (score 3):

```
from random import choice
elem = choice (some_list)
```

Comment: doesn't he want to shuffle the list, then get the index of the users choice? I agree this is the best way to do what he wants if it's just random select (and the end result Is the same, so far at least, either way)

Comment: Yes, this solution misses the part of getting the index of the users choice.

Comment: the combination of a deterministic phenomenon and a nondeterministic phenomenon is a non deterministic phenomenon, so you can combine them .

Answer (score 1):

If you are only trying to select a random number (and asking for input is only a means to achieve that goal), then you should really look into [`random.choice`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice). It does exactly what you need, and you won't have to spend time shuffling your list

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access values of an array like so:

```
s[ans]
```

But first you may have to convert ans to an integer (and handle cases where a user sends something that's not a number!)

```
try:
    i = int(s)
except ValueError:
    i = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You've edited your question to declare the original version "solved" and then added a second one. In the future, don't do that; accept the answer that solved the problem for you, then create a new question. (And you should still accept the answer that solved your original problem!) But this time only, here's a second answer:

> Done that, I want to repeat the random extraction until user digits something like "stop" (here I am) and then sum all the value extracted until "stop" string. How can I do this last point?

I'm assuming you're on Python 2, and using the `input` function so the user can just type `2` and you get the number `2` instead of the string `"2"`. (If you're using Python 3, `input` works like Python 2's `raw_input`, so see the second version.)

So:

```
s=[7777,5454,75000,4545,787,16000,1000,9888,7854,12223]
random.shuffle(s)
values = []
while True:
    ans=input('Press a number from 0 to 9')
    if ans == 'stop':
        break
    values.append(s[ans])
print sum(values)
```

Note that the user will have to type `"stop"` with the quotes this way. If the user instead types `stop` (or `10`, for that matter), the program will quit with an exception. It would be much better to use `raw_input` instead, and do something like this:

```
s=[7777,5454,75000,4545,787,16000,1000,9888,7854,12223]
random.shuffle(s)
values = []
while True:
    ans=raw_input('Press a number from 0 to 9, or stop when done')
    if ans == 'stop':
        break
    try:
        index = int(ans)
        values.append(s[ans])
    except ValueError:
        print '{} is not a number or the word stop'.format(ans)
    except IndexError:
        print '{} is not between 0 and 9.'.format(ans)
print sum(values)
```

You may recognize that this `values = []`, `while`, `values.append` pattern is exactly what list comprehensions and iterators are for. And you can easily factor out all the user input into a generator function that just `yield`s each `s[ans]`, and then just `print sum(userChoices())`, without having to build up a list at all. But I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

```
ans = 0
s = [7777,5454,75000,4545,787,16000,1000,9888,7854,12223]
ans_sums = []
while ans != 'stop': # while the input is not 'stop'
    random.shuffle(s)
    ans = raw_input('Press a number from 0 to 9: ') # this returns the input as a string
    if ans == 'stop':
        break
    else:
        ans_sums.append(int(s[ans])) # adds s[ans] to ans_sums.
        # it must be converted to an integer first because raw_input returns it as a string
return sum(s[ans])
```

Alternatively, you can do something like:

```
ans = 0
s = [7777,5454,75000,4545,787,16000,1000,9888,7854,12223]
ans_sums = 0
while ans != 'stop': # while the input is not 'stop'
    random.shuffle(s)
    ans = input('Press a number from 0 to 9: ')
    if ans == 'stop':
        break
    else:
        ans_sums += s[ans] # adds s[ans] to ans_sums
return ans_sums
```

This avoids creating a list and accomplishes the same job: finds the sum of all the input.